# jQuery function only inside a specific div ID

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have the following function that I only want to run inside `<div id="imgWrapper">`

I have tried a few things with parent but I cannot seem to figure this out.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(
        function () {
            $("img").each(function () {
                var src = $(this).attr("src");
                if (src.substring(0, 1) == "/")
                    $(this).attr("src", "http://serverName.com/" + src.substring(1))
            });

        }
     ); 
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put space in the selector it's a `descendant-selector`:

```
$(document).ready(
    function () {
        $("#imgWrapper img").each(function () { // <<<<<<<=======
            var src = $(this).attr("src");
            if (src.substring(0, 1) == "/")
                $(this).attr("src", "http://serverName.com/" + src.substring(1))
        });

    }
 );
```

`descendant-selector` [docs](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/):

> Description: Selects all elements that are descendants of a given ancestor.

Comment: I don't think you need `function () {` in there? I think OP made a mistake in having a anonymous function there..

Comment: @SKS. Yes you do. read the API: `.ready( handler )
- handler A **function** to execute after the DOM is ready.`

Answer (score 0):

To select just the `img` elements that are descendants of the `imgWrapper` div, change this line:

```
$("img").each(function () {
```

to this:

```
$("#imgWrapper img").each(function () {
```

Answer (score 0):

without see your html change this `$(img)` for `$("div#imgWrapper img")` or `$("img", 'div#imgWrapper')`